# Ruby hash find base on key value and return an array

Tags: ruby

I have the following array of hashes:

```
{
"itens": 
  [
    {"year": "2018", "right": true},
    {"year": "2017", "right": true},
    {"year": "2019", "right": false}
  ]
}
```

I need to find inside the hashes and return an array containing the year value. Only when the key "right" has value true.

```
[2018, 2017]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `h` your data structure

```
h[:itens].select { |item| item[:right] }.map { |item| item[:year].to_i }
```

You can add `.uniq` if you want each year just one time

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, looping only once:

```
h[:itens].each_with_object([]) { |i, arr| arr << i[:year].to_i if i[:right] }
# => [2018, 2017]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
items.select { |_| _['right'] }.map { |_| _['year'] }
```

Comment: `_` in block parameters is supposed to be used when a parameter is unused inside the block.

Comment: Depends on your coding style. Using `_` as a parameter when it’s the sole parameter, is considered valid and acceptable style.

Comment: Yes, `_` is a valid local variable and therefore can be used within a block, but the main reason for using an underscore (or any string beginning with an underscore) as a block variable is to tell the reader that that *that variable is not used in the block calculation*, so no, it's not an acceptable style.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
data[:itens].keep_if{|a| a[:right]}.map{|b| b[:year].to_i}
# => [2018, 2017]
```

Or, Alternatively

```
data[:itens].map{|a| a[:year].to_i if a[:right]}
# => [2018, 2017]
```